# Nodemon starts 2 instances of node when executed as a module in a javascript file

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, nodemon, node-debugger

I am trying to execute a node application through nodemon. I have a `index.js` file as entry point of my application and a `main.js` file as:

```js
var nodemon = require('nodemon');
/**
* some setup done
*/
nodemon({}).on('quit', ()=> {...});
```

with the config `nodemon.json` as:

```js
{
  "env": {
    ...
  },
  "execMap": {
      "js": "node --inspect --max-old-space-size=4096"
  },
  "watch": [
    "src/server",
    "config",
    "dist"
  ]
}
```

When i execute the `main.js` via npm script and run `ps` command in terminal, I am seeing 2 instances of my node application being run as:

```sh
12752 ttys001    0:02.53 /Users/testUser/.nvm/versions/node/v8.17.0/bin/node --inspect --max-old-space-size=4096 index.js
12777 ttys001    0:02.61 /Users/testUser/.nvm/versions/node/v8.17.0/bin/node --inspect --max-old-space-size=4096 --inspect-port=9230 /Users/testUser/projects/nodeProj/index.js
```

Also I am only able to attach node debugger on `PORT 9230` not on `9229`!
Why is such thing happening?

Comment: Why not just run the following command `nodemon index.js` this will exec your node application using nodemon.

Comment: My application requires a build to be made by webpack which is done in the `main.js`